# C# how to do the equivalent of the "Type& operator[]" of C++?

Tags: c#, get, indexer

I have the following C# generic class with an indexer:

```
public class MySpecializedContainer<T> where T : new()
{
    private InternalContainer<Element> container;
    public T this[int index]
    {
        set 
        {
            ConvertTToElement( value, container[index] );
        }
        get
        {
            T obj = new T();
            Element elem = container[index];
            ConvertElementToT( elem, obj );
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see my class pretends the internal container of Element is a container of T, which will work as long as I can convert Element to T and vice-versa.

The problem I have with this is the following:

The following will work as expected as it will effectively change the actual element in the internal container:

```
public class MyClass {
   public int a ;
}
MySpecializedContainer<MyClass> container = ...;
MyClass temp = container[18];
temp.a = 5;
container[18] = temp;
```

but this simpler version will not:

```
container[18].a = 5;
```

**This will just change the copy that the get accessor has created in the indexer...**

Is there any way to make this work ?

Otherwise I have a solution to at least make this statement "container[18].a=5" not compiling but I would really like to support it instead.

Thanks

Comment: What does `ConvertTToElement` look like?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `T` in your internal collection?

Comment: Your title and question are two different things.

Comment: Note that even built in collections in CLR does not provide behavior you want - may be better off blocking behavior (try `List<SomeValueType> items` and see if you can make sense of error in case of `items[3].field = 4;` :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can only really do what you want if there is a reference conversion between `Element` and `T`.  Then in your indexer you can just pass back the reference to the internal object cast to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible (without major changes to the way your existing code works).

In order to get this to work the `MyClass` instance returned would need to be smart enough to know when it's changed and to update the underlying `Element` when that happens.  This isn't possible with a mutable field.  If it was a virtual property then you have a shot.

If we modify `MyClass` like so:

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public virtual int a {get;set;}
}
```

Then we can create a special subclass of it within the container:

```
public class MySpecializedContainer<T> where T : new()
{
    private class MySubClass : MyClass
    {
        private Element wrappedElement;
        public MySubClass(Element wrappedElement)
        {
            this.wrappedElement = wrappedElement;
        }
        public override int a
        {
            set
            {
                base.a = value;
                wrappedElement.Update(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to update the `ConvertElementToT` accordingly as well so that you create a new instance of `MySubClass` and pass in the appropriate `Element` object.

So the lesson here is don't use public fields.

Comment: +1. Nice example of how one can do that too. In generic case (as OP wanted) one would have to dynamically build proxy class derived from T and wrapping all methods to redirect to inner class...